# Docker disables my wifi adapter (due to company policies)

Tags: docker, hyper-v

My work laptop is installed with some policies that disable my wifi adapter when it detects a LAN connection.

When I install Docker for Windows 10, my wifi is disabled because there’s a Hyper-V ethernet.

Is there any workaround for this without compromising the policies?

Comment: try https://forums.docker.com/t/wifi-adapter-disabled-when-hyper-v-network-adapter-enabled-native/18063/14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking around the Internet for a while now and there seems to be no solution for the Hyper-V.

However, the new version of Docker offers to work on WSL 2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) instead of Hyper-V, which doesn't cause this issue anymore for me now.

So for those who are experiencing the same problem, I guess you just need to install the latest Docker and choose WSL instead of Hyper-V. It also depends on your Windows 10 versions as well, as it may not support WSL. However, I think it's a pretty unique case where there's a policy applied on a computer like that.